Dit-on préférablement: À quel prix ils ont payé cette maison ou Quel prix ils ont payé cette maison?
Phrase contextuelle

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su quel prix ils ont payé la maison.

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su à quel prix ils ont payé la maison.



Il y a deux Monseigneur Lavigne ici ? https://french.stackexchange.com/users/34352/monseigneur-lavigne

Dans "j'ai su quel prix ils ont payé la maison" le verpe payer a 2 compléments d'objet directs, ce qui est théoriquement incorrect en Français. Mais, "payer quelquechose X euros" est idiomatique.

Je pense que la première phrase passe mieux :

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su quel prix ils ont payé la maison.

Mais je préfère :

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su quel prix ils ont payé pour la maison.

Avec à, ce pourrait être :

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su à quel prix ils ont acheté la maison.


Sinon :

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su combien leur a coûté la maison.


J'aurais mis quel prix ils avaient payé la maison, personnellement.

@Frank Oui, le plus-que-parfait est implicite sur l'antériorité, mais elle ne faisait déjà guère de doute.

O tempora, o mores! Qualis artifex pereo!

+1, je me demande même si "payer quelque chose à un prix" n'est pas tout simplement incorrect.

@guillaume31 On en trouve bien trop d'occurrences pour le qualifier d'incorrect mais c'est de moins en moins idiomatique, oui.

une autre façon aussi courante voir plus : "combien ils ont payé leur maison"

@XouDo Oui, ou combien ils ont payé cette maison ou leur nouvelle maison s'ils en ont déjà une.

La première version sans le "pour" sonne faux pour moi, quand j'essaie de la reformuler il manque un mot. Tandis que la version "à quel prix ils ont payé", bien qu'un peu moins naturelle que "payé pour" ou que "à quel prix ils ont acheté" m'apporte une idée d'un prix non monétaire, sans que je ne sache l'expliquer. Et pour nuancer les résultats de ce ngram, "payé à un prix exorbitant" est correct.

@Kaiido Le NGram n'indique pas que la forme "payé à un prix exorbitant" est incorrecte, juste qu'elle est en perte de vitesse face à la forme sans préposition (qui sonne faux pour toi, ce qui m'étonne).

Alors, ma remarque sur "le prix exorbitant" tentait de remarquer que la requète ngram n'est pas vraiment ciblée exclusivement sur l'utilisation qui en est faite sur cette page, mais qu'elle englobe aussi des formes où le mot "prix" sera suivi d'un adjectif qui changera complètement la donne quant à l'acceptabilité de la phrase. Donc, bien que je sois d'accord avec guillaume qu'utiliser "payer quelque chose à un prix" tel quel semble incorrect, le ngram ne fait pas la distinction avec les cas où ce prix est completé par un adjectif.

Ça me semble plus naturel de dire à quel prix à mon avis.
En effet la phrase elle même n'est pas exactement celle que j'aurais utilisé en premier lieu.
Dans une discussion de tous les jours je dirais plutôt

J'ai compris la situation quand j'ai su à quel prix ils avaient acheté la maison

Je dirais plus achète pour un bien / un objet, et paye pour un service / une personne, mais les deux sont possible.
